# Using \pause and multiple tikzpictures in one slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

I have two `tickpicture` blocks. What I need, is to use `\pause` (or overlay) another plots on top of each one:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{Figures/plot.pdf}};
        \draw (0., 1.5) node {\small $\Delta R({\mu,\tau})$ };
    \pause    \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{Figures/plotmodified.pdf}};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

       \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{Figures/plot2.pdf}};
       \pause    \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{Figures/plot2modified.pdf}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the above creates two news slides ie one after the first and another after the second `\pause` - Is it possible to have plots changed simultaneously?

Comment: Why don't you use `\only<2>{...}` to add the text which should be visible only on the second slide ?

Comment: Please always post compilable code rather than mere fragments. Also, what does this have to do with the LaTeX 3 project?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter. I've just done it. You can correct my english mistakes :P

Answer (score 1):

With *beamer*, several commands can be used for overlay specifications (cf [here](https://fr.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/20/beamer-series-pt4.html))

The following code will create two slides on one frame, the first one containing images *a* and *b* and the seconde one images *b* and *c*.

`\draw (0., 1.5) node {\small $\Delta R({\mu,\tau})$ };` is not between `only` braces so it will always appear. I moved it at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment to not overwrite it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1>{\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{example-image-a}};}
    \only<2>{\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{example-image-b}};}
    \draw (0., 1.5) node {\small $\Delta R({\mu,\tau})$ };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1>{\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{example-image-b}};}
    \only<2>{\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.44\textheight]{example-image-c}};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```